# Python Poetry [EnvCommandError] when adding a package

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, python-poetry

Python's Poetry always throws me `[EnvCommandError]` whenever I try to add a package. This same error appears also when I try to install dependencies i.e. poetry install

Mind that,

1) I installed `poetry` correctly (using curl which is provided in their website)

2) I am trying to integrate poetry with Docker, so I'm planning to entirely isolate the development with docker only not with any other virtual environment (if there is a 'better' way to do this kindly say so)

3) I'm in the first stage of development:setting up. Nothing's really concrete yet and I'm trying to first organize the packages I'm gonna use and this is the error I get

Initialization is fine:

```
poetry init
```

it shows interactive installation
but with modification or any kind of using the poetry:

```
poetry add bs4
```

it returns me:

```
[EnvCommandError]
Command ['C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\muser-py3.7\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-'    
] errored with the following return code 101, and output:
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -'
input was : import sys
if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
    print(sys.real_prefix)
elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
    print(sys.base_prefix)
else:
    print(sys.prefix)

Exception trace:
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.7\cleo\application.py in run() at line 94
   status_code = self.do_run(input_, output_)
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\application.py in do_run() at line 88
   return super(Application, self).do_run(i, o)
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.7\cleo\application.py in do_run() at line 197
   status_code = command.run(input_, output_)
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\commands\command.py in run() at line 77
   return super(BaseCommand, self).run(i, o)
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.7\cleo\commands\base_command.py in run() at line 136
   self.initialize(input_, output_)
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\commands\env_command.py in initialize() at line 33
   self.poetry.file.parent, o, self.poetry.package.name
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\env.py in create_venv() at line 298
   return VirtualEnv(venv)
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\env.py in __init__() at line 483
   self._base = Path(self.run("python", "-", input_=GET_BASE_PREFIX).strip())
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\env.py in run() at line 539
   return super(VirtualEnv, self).run(bin, *args, **kwargs)
 C:\Users\username\.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\env.py in run() at line 388
   raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
```